# Connection timeout when sharing internet with password

Tags: macos, network, internet-sharing, wifi

I have a MacBook Pro with Mountain Lion 10.8. I am connecting to the Internet via a USB Internet Key. I enabled internet sharing via WiFi.

My friend has a MacBook Pro with Lion 10.7.

When I enable WPA2 Personal with a password, he gets "connection timeout" when clicking on my network name (even before entering the passcode). When I select "none" for security (no passcode), he has no issues connecting.

By request, I've added a screenshot showing that my only options are WPA2 or 'None':
[image]

Comment: Note that a iPhone was able to connect to my network without problems.

Comment: Checkout: http://tidbits.com/article/13158 for details on how Mountain Lion changed internet sharing and issues with using WEP.  It indicates, WEP will be allowed if you hold down the option key.

Comment: Which version of Lion is running your friend's MacBook Pro?

Comment: I wouldn't advise any return to WEP. WEP is simply **false security**!

Answer (score 1):

To try to make things clear let's say you have 2 Mac named:

- Alex
- Bob

Here is the scheme of your small home network :

```
Internet --- USB --- Alex --- WLAN --- Bob
```

If when Bob try to join the wireless network (AirPort or WI-Fi or better WLAN) initiated from Alex,
it gets an immediate rejection, this may be due to a network access
with the wrong security setting.

To check this hypothesis, on Bob, simply go within:

```
System Preferences… > Network > WiFi > Advanced…
```

and look at the column Security.

If it is anything else than `WPA2 Personal`, double click on this network setting to fix it.

If it is already `WPA2 Personal`, double click on this network
setting to check if the registered password is OK.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Internet Sharing over Wi-Fi, you create an ad-hoc Wi-Fi network. Ad-hoc Wi-Fi only supports WEP for encryption on Lion and earlier. You can’t use WPA2 to encrypt an ad-hoc Wi-Fi network unless you are running Mountain Lion.

Edit: I see that you are using channel 36, that means 5GHz Wi-Fi. Try switching to a 2.4GHz channel (1-11, where I live).

Comment: Yet, when creating my ad-hoc network the only options were "none" or "wpa2 personal"

Comment: That’s very unusual…
Can I get a screenshot of the screen where you configure the network with the security menu open?

Comment: see updated question

Comment: changing the channel didn't help

Comment: Of course, since as you indicated it, your network was working on this channel 36, but with security off.

Comment: As very well explained here: http://tidbits.com/article/13158, an `ad-hoc` Wi-Fi network and `InternetSharing` are 2 different ways to build a wireless network. The `ad-hoc` one shouldn't be used anymore because it does only provide WEP which is just **false security**.

Comment: I am sorry. I did not know Mountain Lion used WPA2 since I stopped using Internet Sharing after Lion.

Answer (score -3):

Change security from 40 to 128-bit.

Comment: where do you see 40 or 128??

Comment: This setting was relevant with WEP.